# Run Image Adapter On Demand

Tags: android

I'm using an image adapter to populate a grid view with drawables, I currently set the number of grid elements, the number of columns and the size of them in onCreate based off data passed from the previous activity.
This then generates a grid of random drawables (see code below).

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return gridSize;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
            randomPosition = rng.nextInt(12);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(circleS, circleS));

            imgSet();
            }
            return imageView;
    }
    }//end adapter////////
```

imgSet() gets a random drawable out of the 12 available and sets it as the imageResource for the current imageview, it also triggers another method which assigns a tag value and does other checks.

Now I'm wanting to be able to reload the grid with a new size and format on request with out having to restart the activity.
I tried using grid.invalidateViews() but this seemed to delete all the imageviews except for the last one which did get a new drawable generated like all of them were supposed to have.

So how do I delete all the current imageviews in the grid and then run this image adapter to repopulate the newly sized and formatted grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have code somewhere that looks like this right?

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(<context>);
gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

When you want to change up your gridview column count call.

```
gridview.setNumColumns(<X>);
```

If the data has changed, and you want your views updated too.

```
imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); seems to do the same thing as grid.invalidateViews(): but now that I actually gave the grid new values it's working but the first item in the gridview is staying the old size and not resizing like the rest of the new imageviews

Comment: Got it!! On the first run convertView must not of equaled null so I added an else where I made it set the layout params and now it works perfectly.